# iOS date format with microseconds strange behavior

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, date-format

I have a strange problem with parsing date string. I have a date formatter with format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZ
```

and date string:

```
2012-11-09 10:47:01.999804+01
```

dateFromString method returns nil, but when I change date string to ie:

```
2012-11-09 10:47:01.989804+01
```

it works... Does anyone has idea why there is such limit for microseconds value and how can I properly parse dates like the one above?

I could parse that with regex and cut whole SSSSSS part, but generally sometimes I will need to compare dates so they would not be matching and it will cause more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resolved that issue.

I'm modifying date format and date string to remove microseconds so I can parse date properly. Then I just add microseconds parsed from original date string.

Answer (score 0):

I had no end of niggly issues doing this, finally got it to work but stripped the point seconds off and used the format as follows

`#define DATEFORMATSTRINGTIMEZONE   @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ZZZ"`

a bit like you say.  I have to admit a bit more into the project I realized this was a very difficult method of sharing dates and instead adopted epoch time which has saved all headaches I was having regarding timezones... I'd highly recommend it if you have the luxury of changing the incoming data format.

Whilst I'm not sure why yours doesn't parse, I would question the ZZ instead of the ZZZ at the end given you have +01 not +1?

Comment: Unfortunatelyy I can't change incoming date format, so it has to be left as is. Regarding to time zone, it's parsing correctly, did you have any issues with it?